# MySQL driver issues with INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Tags: python, mysql, python-stackless, python-db-api

I'm trying out the Concurrence framework for Stackless Python. It includes a MySQL driver and when running some code that previously ran fine with MySQLdb it fails.

What I am doing:

1. Connecting to the MySQL database using dbapi with username/password/port/database.
2. Executing `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

This fails with message:

```
Table 'mydatabase.columns' doesn't exist
```

"mydatabase" is the database I specified in step 1.

When doing the same query in the MySQL console after issuing "USE mydatabase", it works perfectly.

Checking the network communication yields something like this:

```
>>>myusername
>>>scrambled password
>>>mydatabase

>>>CMD 3 SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
<<<0

>>>CMD 3 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
<<<255
<<<Table 'mydatabase.columns' doesn't exist
```

Is this a driver issue (since it works in MySQLdb)? Or am I not supposed to be able to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA this way?

If I send a specific "USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA" before trying to query it, I get the expected result. But, I do not want to have to sprinkle my code all over with "USE" queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason.

The driver just echoed the server capability flags back in the protocol handshake, with the exception of compression:

```
## concurrence/database/mysql/client.py ##

client_caps = server_caps 

#always turn off compression
client_caps &= ~CAPS.COMPRESS
```

As the server has the capability...

`CLIENT_NO_SCHEMA   16  /* Don't allow database.table.column */`

...that was echoed back to the server, telling it not to allow that syntax.

Adding `client_caps &= ~CAPS.NO_SCHEMA` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely looks like a driver issue. Maybe the python driver don't support the DB prefix.

Just to be sure, try the other way around: first `use INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and then `SELECT * FROM mydatabase.sometable`

Comment: Thanks, trying the other way around yielded the same error, telling me it has nothing to do with INFORMATION_SCHEMA specifically.